# Parsing IP and joining it to another table with a range of integer representation on BigQuery

Tags: sql, ip, google-bigquery

I need to parse IPs from the 1st table i have (domain) and match it to a range of integer representation and match the IP from domain to the country in IP_location on BigQuery

```
SELECT domain.IP, IP_location.Country
FROM   [webs.domain]
JOIN   [webs.IP_location]
       ON PARSE_IP(rdns.IP) >= IP_location.integer_start 
       AND PARSE_IP(rdns.IP) <= IP_location.integer_end;
```

When i used this query, i got an error

Error: ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name.

Comment: Check this out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618105/geoip-calculation-in-bigquery-performance.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the way to do a join on an inequality as you've described is to do a `CROSS JOIN` with a WHERE clause.

```
SELECT domain.IP, location.Country
FROM   [webs.domain] domain
CROSS JOIN [webs.IP_location] location
WHERE PARSE_IP(domain.IP) >= location.integer_start 
  AND PARSE_IP(domain.IP) <= location.integer_end;
```

Note you might want use CROSS JOIN EACH if this query runs out of resources.
Also, I tweaked your query slightly, since the PARSE_IP call was using rdns.IP, I assumed you meant domain.IP.