# pandas read_gbq returns httplib.ResponseNotReady

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I am using python with google bigquery to do some operations.

I have a Google BigQuery project names data-wagon.
I created a dataset 'vols'
And a table 'flights'.

This is the code I'm testing:

#

import pandas as pd

```
projectid = "data-wagon"

data_frame = pd.read_gbq('SELECT * FROM vols.flights', project_id = projectid)

print data_frame.head()
```

#

When I run it from eclipse, a web page is displayed to ask for authorization, I click Yes but then I have this error message:

---

```
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=....................

If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
application with the command-line parameter 

  --noauth_local_webserver

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\a452618\workspace\BigDataTutos\script_big_query.py", line 16, in <module>

    data_frame = pd.read_gbq('SELECT * FROM vols.flights', project_id = projectid)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\gbq.py", line 334, in read_gbq
    connector = GbqConnector(project_id, reauth = reauth)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\gbq.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.credentials    = self.get_credentials()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\gbq.py", line 111, in get_credentials

    credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, argparser.parse_args([]))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper

    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\tools.py", line 225, in run_flow

    credential = flow.step2_exchange(code, http=http)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper

    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 1982, in step2_exchange

    headers=headers)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1608, in request

    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1350, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1306, in _conn_request

    response = conn.getresponse()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1018, in getresponse
    raise ResponseNotReady()

httplib.ResponseNotReady
```

---

Could any one help me with this?

Best regards,
Ayoub

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you need [to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22723127/3877822) or do [gcloud auth login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login).