# Application Default Credentials not working locally with App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow, google-identity, google-cloud-sdk

Having a tough time getting the Default Application Credentials to load in the dataflow SDK when running locally in a java app engine project developing on OS X. Runs fine when deployed.

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#toolgaesdk) the dev app server doesn't support them, and you're meant to use the gcloud command line tool's command: `gcloud preview app run` - but according to the official Google Group for the SDK [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-cloud-sdk/gcloud$20preview$20app$20run%7Csort:date/google-cloud-sdk/TX0FoWPStTo/7Zy6YABYEwAJ) that command was deprecated in Jan 2016.

So I seem to be stuck between a rock and a hard place... Does anyone know how to get the Application Default Credentials to work locally with an App Engine app?

I'm trying to use the Dataflow API and it just throws up when it starts making use of the cloud storage api which is the first thing the Pipeline does because it can't seem to load the correct credentials from the environment variables ( that are definitely set on the ENV and in the appengine-web.xml `<env-variables>` element ) or from the `~/.config/cloud/default_application_credentials.json` file.

Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access BigQuery from local App Engine development server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349189/unable-to-access-bigquery-from-local-app-engine-development-server)

Answer (score 6):

Can you try running the following command and see if it solves it?

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

Answer (score 3):

This is fully supported (but poorly documented) within the dev appserver. There is a very well answered question that gives you step by step instructions here: [Unable to access BigQuery from local App Engine development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349189/unable-to-access-bigquery-from-local-app-engine-development-server)