# App engine project-1 trying to access BQ in project-2?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

My App engine is running in project-1. I want to access the BQ present in project-2. How can i make app engine in project-1 access the BQ present in project-2?

Answer (score 1):

You should request "can view" (or "can edit") permissions on the dataset of your interest. Owner of project-2 (or respective dataset) will be able to do so.
You don't need to be present on project level and in some cases it is not even appropriate - but you must have appropriate permissions on dataset level

If, by chance, you are the owner of project-2 or respective dataset - you can easily do this by following below instructions
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-web-ui#sharedataset

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to add the default service account of "project-1" to the permissions list of "project-2":

- within the cloud console go to the permissions section of project-1
- select the service accounts sub tab
- look for the default service account (or create a new one)
- add the service account to the permissions of project-2

**EDIT**

You need to create your client in a fashion that uses the applications default service account. For example if you're using python it would look something like:

```
# Grab the application's default credentials from the environment.
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
# Construct the service object for interacting with the BigQuery API.
bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
```

Now with your PK file you can launch the dev appserver in a fashion that the same client client will work correctly: [Unable to access BigQuery from local App Engine development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349189/unable-to-access-bigquery-from-local-app-engine-development-server)

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I was given with service acct and Pk12 file for project-2. I have used these in project-1 App engine. Do i need to create client id in project-2 so that i can use it in App engine? If i follow these steps, i am able to run the App engine code correctly in my local machine but not in the cloud. When i run the App engine code in the cloud i see invalid token or 401 authorized error.

Comment: You would use the pk12 file for local development. The convention for running in the cloud is by following my steps or those of @Mikhail

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I want to design my App so that it can be run locally and on the cloud. How would i do that without PK12 file?

Comment: I have one more basic question. How can i create BQ service without PK12 file. When i create the BQ client  (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-api-quickstart) will the BQ service be created using the default service account?

Comment: When i try to get the BQ service using the default service account, i am getting the bigquery_service instantiated to null. Then i did bigquery_service.getServiceAccountId() and i got null for my service account.