# Bigquery streaming API timeout error

Tags: google-bigquery

We're using bigquery streaming API. All went well until recently (no code change) - 
In the last few hours we get many errors like:

> "The API call urlfetch.Fetch() took too long to respond and was
>   cancelled. Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27"

or

> "Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL"

The insert call is done on a python deferred process and is retried again after a wait.

Questions:

- How can we check if it's our internal issue or a general problem with
  big query?
- Can we increase the 5000 timeout?

Comment: Are you able to obtain a jobId, if so please post it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running in appengine? If so, you can do this:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(60)
```

That said, streaming ingestion shouldn't be anywhere close to the default 5 second error. There was a networking configuration issue with streaming ingestion, it should be resolved now.

Are you still seeing the issues?

Comment: Yes. Using App engine, but I don't directly import urlfetch. Where should I add the import? BTW - the frequency of errors dropped significantly but still had 2 such errors today above 5000ms. average call takes 500-600ms and may peak ~1000ms.

Comment: Using similar code to the python example given in the accepted answer here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049248/how-to-use-bigquery-streaming-insertall-on-app-engine-python). That's why I don't know where to add the function you've mentioned above to extend the urlfetch default deadline.

Comment: does ~600ms to insert ~90 fields (one raw) into bigquery in streaming make sense?