# How do I use the TABLE_QUERY() function in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

A couple of questions about the TABLE_QUERY function:

- The examples show using `table_id` in the query string, are there other fields available?
- It seems difficult to debug. I'm getting "error evaluating subsidiary query" when I try to use it.
- How does `TABLE_QUERY()` work?

Comment: Keep adding such Q&As in the future too. They are great. Google work at BQ team.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The `TABLE_QUERY()` function allows you to write a SQL `WHERE` clause that is evaluated to find which tables to run the query over. For instance, you can run the following query to count the rows in all tables in the `publicdata:samples` dataset that are older than 7 days:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM TABLE_QUERY(publicdata:samples,
    "MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(creation_time) < "
    + "DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7, 'DAY')")
```

Or you can run this to query over all tables that have ‘git’ in the name (which are the `github_timeline` and the `github_nested` sample tables) and find the most common urls:

```
SELECT url, COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE_QUERY(publicdata:samples, "table_id CONTAINS 'git'")
GROUP EACH BY url
ORDER BY url DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Despite being very powerful, `TABLE_QUERY()` can be difficult to use. The `WHERE` clause must be specified as a string, which can be a little bit awkward. Moreover, it can be difficult to debug, since when there is a problem, you only get the error “Error evaluating subsidiary query”, which isn’t always helpful.

**How it works:**

`TABLE_QUERY()` essentially executes two queries. When you run `TABLE_QUERY(<dataset>, <table_query>)`, BigQuery executes `SELECT table_id FROM <dataset>.__TABLES_SUMMARY__ WHERE <table_query>` to get the list of table IDs to run the query on, then it executes your actual query over those tables.

The `__TABLES__` portion of that query may look unfamiliar. `__TABLES_SUMMARY__` is a meta-table containing information about tables in a dataset. You can use this meta-table yourself. For example, the query `SELECT * FROM publicdata:samples.__TABLES_SUMMARY__` will return metadata about the tables in the `publicdata:samples` dataset.

**Available Fields:**

The fields of the `__TABLES_SUMMARY__` meta-table (that are all available in the `TABLE_QUERY` query) include:

- `table_id`: name of the table.
- `creation_time`: time, in milliseconds since 1/1/1970 UTC, that the table was created. This is the same as the `creation_time` field on the table.
- `type`: whether it is a view (2) or regular table (1).

The following fields are *not* available in `TABLE_QUERY()` since they are members of `__TABLES__` but not `__TABLES_SUMMARY__`. They're kept here for historical interest and to partially document the `__TABLES__` metatable:

- `last_modified_time`: time, in milliseconds since 1/1/1970 UTC, that the table was updated (either metadata or table contents). Note that if you use the `tabledata.insertAll()` to stream records to your table, this might be a few minutes out of date.
- `row_count`: number of rows in the table.
- `size_bytes`: total size in bytes of the table.

**How to debug**

In order to debug your `TABLE_QUERY()` queries, you can do the same thing that BigQuery does; that is, you can run the the metatable query yourself. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM publicdata:samples.__TABLES_SUMMARY__ 
WHERE MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(creation_time)  < 
   DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7, 'DAY')
```

lets you not only debug your query but also see what tables would be returned when you run the `TABLE_QUERY` function. Once you have debugged the inner query, you can put it together with your full query over those tables.

Comment: Can `TABLE_QUERY`s be concatenated in any way? I've tried `,` and `JOIN` but neither seems acceptable at that point in the query. Seems like they should be `,`-able, no?

Comment: Yes, you can concatenate them with ,.  You might need to wrap in a subselect, as in `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE_QUERY(...)), (SELECT * FROM TABLE_QUERY(...))`

Comment: Hi Jordan. TABLE_QUERY fails if the project_id contains a "-" hyphen. For example project-data:dataset_id. This is problematic. Any suggestions?

Comment: The answer: use []. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787279/google-bigquery-using-table-query-if-project-id-contains-a-hyphen

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Jordan!

Comment: For partition tables use [dataset.partition_table$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__]

Answer (score 5):

Alternative answer, for those moving forward to Standard SQL:

- BigQuery Standard SQL doesn't support TABLE_QUERY, but it supports * expansion for table names.
- When expanding table names *, you can use the meta-column _TABLE_SUFFIX to narrow the selection.
- Table expansion with * only works when all tables have compatible schemas.

For example, to get the average worldwide NOAA GSOD temperature between 2010 and 2014:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AVG(temp) avg_temp, _TABLE_SUFFIX y
FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa.gsod_20*` #every year that starts with "20"
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "10" AND "14" #only years between 2010 and 2014
GROUP BY y
ORDER BY y
```

Comment: This works, but seems like it involves table scans for all tables. Puzzling that they didn't provide a better replacement for TABLE_QUERY.