# BQ Tables Meta-Data: 0s in the size_bytes & row_count fields

Tags: google-bigquery

I found Jordan's Q&A very educating regarding BQ objects Meta Data...
[How do I use the TABLE_QUERY() function in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22734777/how-do-i-use-the-table-query-function-in-bigquery)

I went on to analyze my data sets using a query similar to

```
SELECT *,size_bytes/row_count as avg_row_size 
FROM publicdata:samples.__TABLES__
order by avg_row_size desc
```

I get all 0s in the size_bytes & row_count fields. Both on my dataset (I am charged for nearly 20 TB, so it cannot be 0), and on the public data set.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong; these numbers aren't actually populated. Setting them in a reasonably performant way is going to be a little bit tricky. I'm tempted to say we should just drop those fields, but if they're useful, we can look into filling them out.

Comment: I find them very useful. 1 - as a mean to monitor all my loading processes run fine and populate all relevant table. 2. Analyze the datasets in order to optimize, both queries and storage volume. 3. size_bytes & row_count per field can be another great addition to available metadata. it would be very useful for schema optimization.