# bigquery dataset design, multiple vs single tables for storing the same type of data

Tags: google-bigquery

im planning to build a new ads system and we are considering to use google bigquery.

ill quickly describe my data flow :

Each User will be able to create multiple ADS. (1 user, N ads)
i would like to store the ADS impressions and i thought of 2 options.

1- create a table for impressions , for example table name is :Impressions fields : (userid,adsid,datetime,meta data fields...)
  in this options of all my impressions will be stored in a single table.

main pros : ill be able to big data queries quite easily.
main cons: table will be hugh, and with multiple queries, ill end up paying too much (:

option 2 is to create table per ads

for example, ads id 1 will create
Impression_1 with fields (datetime,meta data fields)

pros: query are cheaper, data table is smaller
cons: todo big dataquery sometimes ill have to create a union and things will complex

i wonder what are your thoughts regarding this  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BigQuery it's easy to do this, because you can create tables per each day, and you have the possibility to query only those tables.

And you have [Table wildcard functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#tablewildcardfunctions), which are a cost-effective way to query data from a specific set of tables. When you use a table wildcard function, BigQuery only accesses and charges you for tables that match the wildcard. Table wildcard functions are specified in the query's FROM clause.

Assuming you have some tables like:

```
mydata.people20140325
mydata.people20140326
mydata.people20140327
```

You can query like:

```
SELECT 
  name
FROM 
  (TABLE_DATE_RANGE(mydata.people, 
                    TIMESTAMP('2014-03-25'), 
                    TIMESTAMP('2014-03-27'))) 
WHERE 
  age >= 35
```

Also there are [Table Decorators](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators):

Table decorators support relative and absolute `<time>` values. Relative values are indicated by a negative number, and absolute values are indicated by a positive number.

To get a snapshot of the table at one hour ago:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [data-sensing-lab:gartner.seattle@-3600000]
```

There is also [TABLE_QUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22734777/how-do-i-use-the-table-query-function-in-bigquery), which you can use for more complex queries.

Comment: this is really nice feature but im not so sure its match my needs.
i will have
ads_1
ads_2
ads_3


each one of the above will store relevant data for all dates and time.
for example :
ads_1
will have : 
1/1/2000,kuku
1/1/2001,kuku2
1/2/2001,kuku2
1/1/2015


and ads_2..N will be similar.

and i will want to do something like:

select * from ads_ALL   where field = 'kuku'  //just for example.

Comment: I think that's a bad approach, you should have `ads_20150101` a table per day. And inside that table have a column that identifies your ads ID.

Comment: You should consider 
1. costs - portioned data query costs are much cheaper, 
2. maintenance - As BQ is "append only", partitioning the data-set into tables lets you update or delete portions of the data.
I would recommend on breaking down the data into tables, and certainly recommend on breaking it down also by period.

Comment: N.N - so both 1+2 ...i didnt think of it like this but now you opened my eyes into a whole new thinking..  do you think that having millions of tables under dataset is not going to be a problem  (google prb)?

Comment: If you choose to have millions of tables, you won't be able to maintain them. You need to limit yourself to per day tables, or per hours table. Not sure why you still want to go with your solution. You posted your question, and we proposed you the best outcome. I would create table for each day, that's 365 tables in a year.

Comment: Note if the `TABLE_DATE_RANGE()` syntax is too restrictive for your table names, there is always the `TABLE_QUERY()` function which allows you to build arbitrary SQL to find table names. Please note that you are limited to 1K tables per query, and that adding a lot of tables can add considerable latency to your queries.

Comment: ill have to provide stat, ill have to query the 1b entries all over again and again and in BQ , as far as i understood, i will pay a lot for it, bcs i pay for scan table and not by the 
Regarding the maintenance comment, what exactly do you mean "you wont be able to maintain them” ?

Comment: You won't be able to delete old data, deduplicate data easiliy if you have so many tables. And as Jordan says, there is a 1K limit per query. If you have tables per day, you can choose to delete data per days. Also the interface will list you only 1K tables, the rest of your tables will be accessibly only via API or BQ console tool. I strongly advise not reinvent the wheel here, and consider doing as we suggest.