# TABLE_QUERY fails when trying to use last_modified_time

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an existing query which uses TABLE_QUERY(), and filters the results based on creation_time:

```
SELECT 
     *
FROM (TABLE_QUERY( project_114151_dataset , "MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(creation_time) > DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -45, 'DAY') AND REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, r'^fact_[0-9]{8}$') "))
```

I want to change the query to run based on last_modified_time; since it is also a timestamp in msec, I changed the query to be as follows

```
SELECT 
     *
FROM (TABLE_QUERY( project_114151_dataset , "MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(last_modified_time) > DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -45, 'DAY') AND REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, r'^fact_[0-9]{8}$') "))
```

However, when running I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Error evaluating subsidiary query
```

Not sure why I'm getting this error; I've verified that this field exists by running the following query, and it does indeed return in the results:

```
SELECT * FROM project_114151_dataset.__TABLES__ 
WHERE MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(creation_time)  < 
DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7, 'DAY')
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only fields available in the `TABLE_QUERY()` function are: `project_id`, `dataset_id`, `table_id`, `creation_time`, and `type`. They are the feilds returned by the `__TABLES_SUMMARY__` pseudo-table. (try `SELECT * FROM project_114151_dataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`).

Comment: I understand that this has changed?
I was basing my syntax on your post found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22734777/how-do-i-use-the-table-query-function-in-bigquery

Would it be possible to update the documentation as well?

Comment: @GilAdirim what has changed on that post?

Comment: @Pentium10 on your answer I've linked to, you explain that table_query() uses the same logic as behind __TABLES__, which includes the last_modifed_time field; whereas Jordan's answer implies that the logic works by returning data from __TABLES_SUMMARY__ which does not.

So which is the correct?

Comment: We switched to `__TABLES_SUMMARY__` for performance reasons... it is much faster than `__TABLES__`

Answer (score 1):

The expression inside TABLE_QUERY cannot use data form the table, it has to use constants and free functions (such as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) only.