# Get the last data of my google analytics dataset

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to get the last table processed with Google Analytics dataset data using this code:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_QUERY(77xx77xx,'table_id CONTAINS "ga_sessions" 
      AND last_modified_time= (Select MAX(last_modified_time) 
                              FROM 77xx77xx.__TABLES__
                              where table_id contains "ga_sessions")'
            )
```

This not working. The BigQuery interface returns me the following error:

> Error: Encountered "" at line 4, column 17.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

I Found a soluction. Follows:

```
SELECT table_id AS tabela FROM [77xx77xx.__TABLES__] 
WHERE table_id CONTAINS "ga_sessions_20" ORDER BY tabela DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work (I think it is what you were getting at in your self-answer, but this shows the complete query):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_QUERY(77xx77xx,
  'table_id contains "ga_sessions" AND 
  table_id IN (
    SELECT table_id 
    FROM publicdata:samples.__TABLES__
    ORDER BY creation_time DESC 
    LIMIT 1)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ' instead of ":

```
 CONTAINS 'ga_sessions'
```

look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22734777/how-do-i-use-the-table-query-function-in-bigquery) answer for more information about how to work with TableQuery