# Google BigQuery: Using TABLE_QUERY if project_id contains a hyphen "-"

Tags: sql, exec, eval, google-bigquery

This extends Jordan's post here:
[How do I use the TABLE_QUERY() function in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22734777/how-do-i-use-the-table-query-function-in-bigquery)

Here is an example of working TABLE_QUERY SQL.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM TABLE_QUERY(publicdata:samples,
    "MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(creation_time) < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7, 'DAY')")
```

However, TABLE_QUERY fails if the project_id contains a "-" hyphen. For example:

```
SELECT whatever
FROM TABLE_QUERY(other-public-data:samples,
    "MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(creation_time) < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7, 'DAY')")
```

Likely because the interpreter sees a subtraction operation.

Without an "eval" (JavaScript) or "exec" (Python) operation to convert strings to variable names, are there any suggestions to get this working in BigQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Escape" with []:

```
SELECT whatever
FROM TABLE_QUERY([other-public-data:samples],
  "MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(creation_time) < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7, 'DAY')")
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you Felipe. This works! The one time I tested [], I had an additional error that obfuscated this as the correct syntax. Thanks!