# BigQuery Wildcard tables with Regex and date range

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, wildcard

Is it possible to combine the [table wildcard functions as documented here?](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#tablewildcardfunctions)

I've taken a look through the [Table Query functions SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22734777/how-do-i-use-the-table-query-function-in-bigquery), but doesn't quite seem to cover my use case.

I have table names in the format: `s_CUSTOMER_ID_YYYYMMDD`

I can find all the tables for a customer ID using:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_QUERY([project:dataset], 
                 'REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, r"^s_CUSTOMER_ID")')
```

And I can find all the tables for a date range via:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([project:dataset],
                       TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01'),
                       TIMESTAMP('2016-03-01')))
```

But how do I query for both at the same time?

I tried using sub queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM    
    (SELECT *
    FROM TABLE_QUERY([project:dataset], 
                     'REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, r"^s_CUSTOMER_ID")'))
    ,(SELECT * 
    FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([project:dataset],
                           TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01'),
                           TIMESTAMP('2016-03-01'))))
```

...but the parser complains of `Error: Can't parse table: project:dataset`.

Adding a dot so they are `project:dataset.` brings an error `Error: Error preparing subsidiary query: Dataset project:dataset. not found`

Are my table names poorly done?  What would be a better way of organising them if so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below quick "solution" - should work and you can improve it based on real/extra requirements you probably have

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  TABLE_QUERY([project:dataset], 
    'REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, r"^s_CUSTOMER_ID") 
    AND RIGHT(table_id, 8) BETWEEN "20160101" AND "20160301"')
```