# UNION of tables using bigquery LegacySQL

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I'm trying without luck to do a query to retrieve the union two tables of events using legacySQL, as standardSQL is not yet supported on data studio.

In standardSQL that would be something like:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
 `com_myapp_ANDROID.app_events_*`,
 `com_myapp_IOS.app_events_*`
```

However, in legacySQL I get an error when trying to refer app_events_*. How do I include all the tables of my events, so I can filter it afterwards on data studio if I can't use the wildcard?

I've tried something like:

```
select * from (TABLE_QUERY(com_myapp_ANDROID, 'table_id CONTAINS "app_events_"'))
```

But not sure if this is the right approach, I get:

> Cannot output multiple independently repeated fields at the same time.
>   Found user_dim_user_properties_value_index and event_dim_date

Edit: in the end this is the result of the query, as you can't use directly FLATTEN with TABLE_QUERY:

```
select
  *
from
  FLATTEN((SELECT * FROM TABLE_QUERY(com_myapp_ANDROID, 'table_id CONTAINS "app_events"')),user_dim.user_properties),
  FLATTEN((SELECT * FROM TABLE_QUERY(com_myapp_IOS, 'table_id CONTAINS "app_events"')),user_dim.user_properties)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular issue you are experiencing is not UNION related - you will see same error message even with just one table if the table has multiple independently repeated fields and you are trying to output them at once. This scenario is specific to Legacy SQL and can be resolved with use of [FLATTEN clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#flatten)
At the same time, most likely you don't actually mean to use `SELECT *` which cause those repeated fields to be in output all at the same time. If you can narrow down your output list - you have slight chance to address it  - but if still few independently repeated fields are in output  - you can use FLATTEN technique

Comment: Maybe my approach is wrong, but all I'm trying is to get a query with all the data available to be used as a datasource on data studio, just like when you select one table as datasource, but with two tables merged, so I wanted all the values and later when using data studio widget's, select which ones to display on each graph.

Comment: Moreover, I believe I can't use FLATTEN with TABLE_QUERY?

Answer (score 3):

Table wildcards don't work in legacy SQL as you have guessed so you have to use the `TABLE_QUERY()` function.

Your approach is right but the first parameter in the TABLE_QUERY function should be the *dataset* name not the first part of the *table* name. Assuming your dataset name is app_events that would look like this:

```
TABLE_QUERY(app_events,'table_id CONTAINS "app_events"')
```

Answer (score 2):

In legacySQL the union table operator is `comma`

```
select * from [table1],[table2]
```

For TABLE_QUERY you would include the dataset name as first param, and the expression for the second

```
select * from (TABLE_QUERY([dataset], 'table_id CONTAINS "event"'))
```

to read more how to debug TABLE_QUERY read this [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22734777/how-do-i-use-the-table-query-function-in-bigquery)

The Web UI automatically flattens you the results, but when there are independent repeated fields you need to flatten with the FLATTEN wrapper.

It takes two params, table, and repeated field eg: `FLATTEN(table, tags)`

Also if TABLE_QUERY is involved you need to subselect probably like

```
select
  *
from
  FLATTEN((SELECT * FROM TABLE_QUERY(com_myapp_ANDROID, 'table_id CONTAINS "app_events"')),user_dim.user_properties)
```

Comment: Yes, but if I do that, I get an error that I don't get on standardSQL, see my edited question

Comment: Yep, that is another concept, it's called FLATTEN. Always try to run a simple query like selectin a field, and not the entire table.