# Random sampling complete rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I know from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375456/random-sampling-in-google-bigquery) that one can do random sampling `RAND`.

`SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE RAND() < percentage`

But this would require a full table scan and incur equivalent cost. I'm wondering if there are more efficient ways?

I'm experimenting with `tabledata.list` API but got `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out` when `index` is very large (i.e. > 10000000). Is this operation not O(1)?

`bigquery
  .tabledata()
  .list(tableRef.getProjectId, tableRef.getDatasetId, tableRef.getTableId)
  .setStartIndex(index)
  .setMaxResults(1L)
  .execute()`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend paging [tabledata.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/list) with [pageToken](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/list#pageToken) and get collect sample rows from each page. This should scale much better.

Another (totally different) option I see is use of [Table Decorators](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators)
You can in loop grammatically generate random time (for snapshot) or time-frame (for range) and query only that portions of data extracting needed data.
Note limitation: This will allow you to sample data that is less than 7 days old.

Comment: My use case is to uniformly sample a small, fixed number of rows without doing the full table IO. The `pageToken` approach would still require going through all rows in a table?

Answer (score 0):

tabledata.list is not especially performant for arbitrary lookups in a table, especially as you are looking later and later into the table.  It is not really designed for efficient data retrieval of an entire table, it's more for looking at the first few pages of data in a table.

If you want to run some operation over all the data in your table, but not run a query, you should probably use an [extract job to GCS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data) instead, and sample rows from the output files.