# Stratified random sampling with BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can I do stratified sampling on BigQuery?

For example, we want a 10% proportionate stratified sample using the category_id as the strata. We have up to 11000 category_ids in some of our tables.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With `#standardSQL`, let's define our table and some stats over it:

```
WITH table AS (
  SELECT *, subreddit category
  FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2018_09` a
), table_stats AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(c) OVER() total 
  FROM (
    SELECT category, COUNT(*) c 
    FROM table
    GROUP BY 1 
    HAVING c>1000000)
)
```

In this setup:

- `subreddit` will be our category
- we only want subreddits with more than 1000000 comments

So, if we want 1% of each category in our sample:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) samples, category, ROUND(100*COUNT(*)/MAX(c),2) percentage
FROM (
  SELECT id, category, c  
  FROM table a
  JOIN table_stats b
  USING(category)
  WHERE RAND()< 1/100 
)
GROUP BY 2
```

[image]

Or let's say we want ~80,000 samples - but chosen proportionally through all categories:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) samples, category, ROUND(100*COUNT(*)/MAX(c),2) percentage
FROM (
  SELECT id, category, c  
  FROM table a
  JOIN table_stats b
  USING(category)
  WHERE RAND()< 80000/total
)
GROUP BY 2
```

[image]

Now, if you want to get the ~same number of samples from each group (let's say, 20,000):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) samples, category, ROUND(100*COUNT(*)/MAX(c),2) percentage
FROM (
  SELECT id, category, c  
  FROM table a
  JOIN table_stats b
  USING(category)
  WHERE RAND()< 20000/c
)
GROUP BY 2
```

[image]

If you want exactly 20,000 elements from each category:

```
SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(cat_samples) samples, category, ROUND(100*ARRAY_LENGTH(cat_samples)/c,2) percentage
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(a ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20000) cat_samples, category, ANY_VALUE(c) c
  FROM table a
  JOIN table_stats b
  USING(category)
  GROUP BY category
)
```

[image]

If you want exactly 2% of each group:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) samples, sample.category, ROUND(100*COUNT(*)/ANY_VALUE(c),2) percentage
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(a ORDER BY RAND()) cat_samples, category, ANY_VALUE(c) c
  FROM table a
  JOIN table_stats b
  USING(category)
  GROUP BY category
), UNNEST(cat_samples) sample WITH OFFSET off
WHERE off<0.02*c
GROUP BY 2
```

[image]

---

If this last approach is what you want, you might notice it failing when you actually want to get data out. An early `LIMIT` similar to the largest group size will make sure we don't sort more data than needed:

```
SELECT sample.*
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(a ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 105000) cat_samples, category, ANY_VALUE(c) c
  FROM table a
  JOIN table_stats b
  USING(category)
  GROUP BY category
), UNNEST(cat_samples) sample WITH OFFSET off
WHERE off<0.02*c
```

Answer (score 11):

I think the simplest way to get a proportionate stratified sample is to order the data by the categories and do an "nth" sample of the data.  For a 10% sample, you want every 10 rows.

This looks like:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by category order by rand()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum % 10 = 1;
```

Note:  This does not guarantee that all categories will be in the final sample.  A category with fewer than 10 rows may not appear.

If you want equal sized samples, then order *within* each category and just take a fixed number:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by category order by rand()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 100;
```

Note:  This does not guarantee that 100 rows exist within each category.  It takes all rows for smaller categories and a random sample of larger ones.

Both these methods are quite handy.  They can work with multiple dimensions at the same time.  The first has a particularly nice feature that it can also work with numeric dimensions as well.

Comment: QQ - Why do you say that _"The first has a particularly nice feature that it can also work with numeric dimensions as well."_? `seqnum` is a number in both cases. The only diff is that in one case you are (trying to) take a **fixed percentage** of samples per category, whereas in the 2nd one you are taking (at most) a **fixed (and equal) number** of samples per category, right?

Comment: @Josh . . . What I mean is that an nth sample will work if you want to stratify by a numeric columns, for instance `row_number() over (order by income)` would also work with the modulo approach.