# Random String Function in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I was trying to generate random string in BigQuery when I encountered this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23376403/1487781).

```
SELECT
    word
FROM
    `publicdata.samples.shakespeare`
WHERE
    RAND() < 10/(
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        `publicdata.samples.shakespeare`)
```

It worked but I need to create a function out of that answer. This is my attempt to convert it but no luck.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
    random_word() AS ( (
        SELECT
            STRING_AGG(word, "_") AS aggd_word
        FROM (
            SELECT
                LOWER(REPLACE(word, "'", "")) AS word
            FROM
                `publicdata.samples.shakespeare`
            WHERE
                RAND() < 10/(
                SELECT
                    COUNT(*)
                FROM
                    `publicdata.samples.shakespeare`)
            LIMIT
                3)) );
SELECT
    random_word();
```

I got this error

```
Table not found: `publicdata.samples.shakespeare`;
failed to parse CREATE [TEMP] FUNCTION statement at [25:9]
```

Comment: Which characters can be in the string? Any UTF-8 code points, or are you specifically targeting `a-zA-Z0-9`, for example? What are the upper and lower bounds on the length of the string?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard `a-zA-Z0-9` is enough. Length of the string is not my concern. But not too long, maybe 64 chars max. Basically just a random string (not UUID) generator.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#limits  - You cannot reference a table in a UDF

Comment: @Bobbylank thank you, need to read the docs more thoroughly

Comment: No problems, I hope you find another way around the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to convert a hash into characters in the desired range:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION MapChar(c INT64) AS (
  CASE
    WHEN c BETWEEN 0 AND 9 THEN 48 + c -- 0 to 9
    WHEN c BETWEEN 10 AND 35 THEN 55 + c -- A to Z
    ELSE 61 + c -- a to z
  END
);

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION RandString() AS ((
  SELECT CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(MapChar(MOD(c, 62))))
  FROM UNNEST(TO_CODE_POINTS(SHA256(CAST(RAND() AS STRING)))) AS c
));

SELECT RandString();
```

You can use`SHA512` instead of `SHA256` if you want a longer string.