# How does sampling random n% records work using RAND() in big query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to get help understanding sql query in bigquery.

If I write query as below, this samples random 1% rows out of total rows which column *DEP_DELAY* are not *null*. Without `RAND()` , total number of rows are `235208`.

```
SELECT COUNT(DEP_DELAY) FROM flights.fedtzcorr WHERE RAND() < 0.1
```

Reading the [document](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/RAND-Function_57344757), it says it creates fifteen digits of precision after the decimal point. So, literaly understanding, I thought RAND() creates 15 digit number 
between `0` and `100,000,000,000,000` ...

> This function generates values of Decimal type with fifteen digits of precision after the decimal point.

How does RAND() sample 1% of rows from total number of rows ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the document you pointed to is documentation related to Dataprep, not BigQuery:

- https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/RAND-Function_57344757

The correct documentation is:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#rand

> Generates a pseudo-random value of type FLOAT64 in the range of [0, 1), inclusive of 0 and exclusive of 1.

So `RAND()` generates a number between 0 and 1. `WHERE RAND() < 0.1` then matches 10% of rows (not 1%). For 1% try `WHERE RAND() < 0.01`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23376403/132438 for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

So the query could be the following:

```
DECLARE deep_delay_count INT64;
DECLARE deep_delay_pct FLOAT64;

SET deep_delay_count = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DEP_DELAY)
                        FROM flights.fedtzcorr
                        WHERE DEP_DELAY IS NOT NULL);
SET deep_delay_pct = IF(deep_delay_count IS NOT NULL, 0.01 * deep_delay_count / deep_delay_count, 0);

SELECT DISTINCT DEP_DELAY
FROM flights.fedtzcorr
WHERE DEP_DELAY IS NOT NULL
  AND RAND() < deep_delay_pct;
```