# How to get all BigQuery (bq) command history?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to get all the bq history of my own / all user. But I could not find anyway to do it. Anyway to retrieve such log or capture it?

- I have tried "bq show -j" already but the result does not include original statement / missing arguments.
- I have tried Stackdriver Logs, it looks similar to bq show with prettyjson argument. So still not the whole command / missing arguments.

Comment: [Click the Link, it can helps you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140104/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-an-extended-or-full-query-history-in-google-bigquery) Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery maintains job history for jobs created in the past six months; nonetheless, you could use the  [`'bq ls'`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_ls) to retrieve the max number of possible results (By default, you are limited to 100,000 results) , as an example, you can use the following command:

```
bq ls -j -n MAX_RESULTS | wc -l
```

This command will count the number of jobs in your project, you have to indicate the MAX_RESULTS you expect to get, the default value is 50. Once you obtain the rows you might consider to use the flag `--format prettyjson` to export your results, as an example:

```
bq ls -j -n 1000 --format prettyjson
```

This command  will show you the last 1000 jobs made in your project in json format.

The `ls` command also could lists objects like datasets, tables, views, transfers configuration and transfers history  in a collection which could be useful for you.

The  [Method: jobs.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list?hl=th) lists all the jobs that you started in the specified project, the [Method: jobs.get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get?hl=th) returns information about a specific job. In the links you could try those APIs, if they works as you wish you can  sue it thru HTTP request or gRPC.

Comment: I think its result is the same thing as bq show. It is just meta data/result but not the statement itself.

Comment: I added another option to my answer.