# How can I undelete a BigQuery table after I already created a new one with the same name?

Tags: google-bigquery

I accidentally deleted a table in BigQuery and I'd very much like to undelete it. I've read the answer in "[How can I undelete a BigQuery table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537720/how-can-i-undelete-a-bigquery-table)" but in my case I already created a table with the same name, and now when I try to copy a snapshot with the timestamp being the time I created the new table with the same name, I get an error saying:

> "error ... invalid snapshot time for table ... cannot read before
>   "

BTW, the timestamp is from a few hours ago. The whole thing happened in the last 24 hours.

So it seems to me that the problem is that BQ is trying to get a snapshot of the new table, while I need a snapshot of the old table with the same name.

Is there a way for me to access a snapshot of the older incarnation of the table to restore it?

Comment: In the other question, it clearly states - "If you have since recreated a table with the same name, you may not be able to undelete the old one."

Comment: Right. "you may not" does not sound definite, so I was hoping there is a way to get the table back.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting an error in the operation described in [How can I undelete a BigQuery table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537720/how-can-i-undelete-a-bigquery-table), I'm afraid you're out of luck.  Undelete / time travel is a best-effort operation.  Sorry about that!