# BigQuery - Undelete table in Web UI

Tags: google-bigquery

I found the [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537720/how-can-i-undelete-a-bigquery-table) how to undelete a table using the API. But how to do with web UI?

Comment: You can run a `SELECT *` query over the old snapshot with a destination table specified, but this will not be a free operation (where as the table copy using the `bq` client is).

Comment: That does not work. I get: Not found table_xyz

Comment: obviously it does not work with table itself as it is deleted - the "trick" is in using table with snapshot at a time when it existed. btw. this approach has limitation - I think table should be deleted not more than 2 weeks ago for it to be "recovered"

Comment: @ElliottBrossard How do you run a SELECT * over a snapshot? What does that command look like?

Comment: Use a snapshot decorator as a suffix of the table name in the FROM clause. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators#snapshot_decorators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify - referenced post uses bq command line tool (rather than API)

"BigQuery Web UI" does not allow you set Source when you do a copy table - only Destination! Source is assumed to be a table that you originated Copy from - but as it is deleted  - it is not available in Navigator - thus not doable!

Meantime, the "Web UI" I can suggest to reproduce this approach is to use respective API Explorer - in this case you should deal with Jobs.Insert with copy in configuration - https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/bigquery/v2/bigquery.jobs.insert

This UI allows you "visually" build and execute any Google API 
In particular, here you can set both Source and Destination so you should be good to go!