# Is there a way to repopulate specific date of Google BigQuery data from Google Firebase Analytics?

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, recover, undelete

I have setup link between Firebase Analytics and BigQuery.  Today I accidentally deleted rows of data from yesterday (tablename_20190926). Is there a way to restore the data, if not, how do I repopulate the data from Firebase Analytics again for a specific date?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase streams its analytics data to BigQuery from the moment you enable the integration. There is no way to repopulate BigQuery with Analytics data from Firebase outside of that stream.

You may be able to recover the data from within BigQuery though. See [Restoring deleted tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#undeletetable) in the documentation, and [How can I undelete a BigQuery table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537720/how-can-i-undelete-a-bigquery-table)

Comment: Is there a way to repopulate from the same stream?  If I go to "Job History -> Project History" I can see each time a new partition table is created.  In fact, there is even a button that says "Repeat Load Job"