# Delete Oldest Duplicate Rows from a BigQuery Table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with >70M rows of data and 2M of duplicates. I want to clean duplicates by keeping the recent original row.

I found a few solutions from here - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675521/delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-bigquery-table)

In which, solutions are only to clean the duplicates and not retain the recent data among the duplicates.

here is another common solution:

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER (partition BY id ORDER BY 
                updatedAt 
                DESC, 
                status DESC) RN 
         FROM   MainTable) 
DELETE FROM cte 
WHERE  RN > 1
```

But it is not supported in BigQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the workaround, which replaces the existing table with unique rows and recent original rows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  `MainTable` AS
SELECT
  id,
  acctId,
  appId,
  createdAt,
  startTime,
  subAcctId,
  type,
  updatedAt,
  userId
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY updatedAt DESC -- the first row among duplicates will be kept, other rows will be removed
      ) RN
  FROM
    `MainTable`)
WHERE
  RN = 1
```

Since we don't have the option to remove a particular column(rn), have to select the required columns while replacing the existing table.

Hope this helps someone. Please share if you have any better solutions.

Comment: you can use `SELECT * EXCEPT(RN)` so you will not need to list all columns

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I think EXCEPT clause will not work directly in that way as per [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-except-clause/). Even if we use which will lead to another nested query.

Comment: i really doubt you did it properly!and what kind of error you got?

Comment: oops Sorry got it. Thank you very much

Comment: see proper syntax in my answer :o) if this helped you - consider voting

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  `MainTable` AS
SELECT * EXCEPT(RN)
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY updatedAt DESC -- the first row among duplicates will be kept, other rows will be removed
      ) RN
  FROM
    `MainTable`)
WHERE
  RN = 1
```