# BigQuery - Delete rows with a limit

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to remove duplicate rows from BigQuery. The duplicate rows have the same data in all the columns. I know how to find the duplicates but I can't find a way to delete all rows but one. What I want to do is basically

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE id = <id> LIMIT 1
```

But that doesn't work. I am not interested in rewriting the entire table

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Use TOP function to get the first one then `DELETE TOP(1) FROM dataset.duplicateTest WHERE ID = 1 `

Comment: Already answered here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675521/delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-bigquery-table

Comment: Thanks, but from my understanding there are only solutions there that includes rewriting entire table.

Comment: TOP did not work for me