# Deduplicate rows in a BigQuery partition

Tags: sql, merge, google-bigquery, duplicates, database-partitioning

I have a table with many duplicated rows - but I only want to deduplicate rows one partition at a time.

How can I do this?

As an example, you can start with a table partitioned by date and filled with random integers from 1 to 5:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `temp.many_random`
PARTITION BY d
AS 
SELECT DATE('2018-10-01') d, fhoffa.x.random_int(0,5) random_int
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 100))
UNION ALL
SELECT CURRENT_DATE() d, fhoffa.x.random_int(0,5) random_int
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 100))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's see what data we have in the existing table:

```
SELECT d, random_int, COUNT(*) c
FROM `temp.many_random`
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

[image]

That's a lot of duplicates!

We can de-duplicate one single partition using `MERGE` and `SELECT DISTINCT *` with a query like this:

```
MERGE `temp.many_random` t
USING (
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM `temp.many_random`
  WHERE d=CURRENT_DATE()
)
ON FALSE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND d=CURRENT_DATE() THEN DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ROW
```

Then the end result looks like this:

[image]

We need to make sure to have the same date in the `SELECT` and the row with `THEN DELETE`. This will delete all rows on that partition, and insert all rows from the `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Inspired by:

- https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-deduplication-14a1206efdbb

To de-duplicate a whole table, see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45311051/132438

Comment: Is there a version of this solution which works for time ingestion partitioned tables?

Judging from the error I'm getting, I can't immediately see how to rewrite this. - `Omitting INSERT target column list is unsupported for ingestion-time partitioned table`

Answer (score 4):

Additional answer - for complex rows that can't use `DISTINCT`:

```sql
MERGE `temp.many_random` t
USING (
  # choose a single row to delete the duplicates
  SELECT a.*
  FROM (
    SELECT ANY_VALUE(a) a
    FROM `temp.many_random` a
    WHERE d='2018-10-01'
    GROUP BY d, random_int # id
  )
)
ON FALSE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND d='2018-10-01' 
  # delete the duplicates
  THEN DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ROW
```

Comment: ANY_VALUE() and GROUP BY is a great pattern to deduplicate when there are many duplicates (in my case: > 300 k).
Works much better than the ROW_NUMBER() approach I used before!

Answer (score 1):

You could also deduplicate for a range of partitions.

```
-- WARNING: back up the table before this operation
-- FOR large size timestamp partitioned table 
-- -------------------------------------------
-- -- To de-duplicate rows of a given range of a partition table, using surrage_key as unique id
-- -------------------------------------------

DECLARE dt_start DEFAULT TIMESTAMP("2019-09-17T00:00:00", "America/Los_Angeles") ;
DECLARE dt_end DEFAULT TIMESTAMP("2019-09-22T00:00:00", "America/Los_Angeles");

MERGE INTO `my_project`.`data_set`.`the_table` AS INTERNAL_DEST
USING (
  SELECT k.*
  FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(original_data LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] k 
    FROM `my_project`.`data_set`.`the_table` AS original_data
    WHERE stamp BETWEEN dt_start AND dt_end
    GROUP BY surrogate_key
  )

) AS INTERNAL_SOURCE
ON FALSE

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
  AND INTERNAL_DEST.stamp BETWEEN dt_start AND dt_end -- remove all data in partiion range
    THEN DELETE

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ROW
```

credit: https://gist.github.com/hui-zheng/f7e972bcbe9cde0c6cb6318f7270b67a