# How to delete duplicates in sql where min(timestamp)

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to delete duplicate lines, leaving only the most updated ones

e.g.: `SCHEMA: user_id, conversation_id, created_at, updated_at`

DATA SAMPLE:

```
Row user_id conversation_id          created_at                  updated_at
1    234        45664        2020-06-05 16:17:01 UTC    2020-06-05 23:27:01 UTC        
2    234        45664        2020-06-05 16:17:01 UTC    2020-06-06 14:34:01 UTC
3    232        45665        2020-06-05 17:23:41 UTC    2020-06-05 18:12:01 UTC
4    232        45665        2020-06-05 17:23:41 UTC    2020-06-07 12:47:01 UTC
```

I want to keep only the most updated row:

```
   Row user_id conversation_id          created_at                  updated_at

    1    234        45664        2020-06-05 16:17:01 UTC    2020-06-06 14:34:01 UTC
    2    232        45665        2020-06-05 17:23:41 UTC    2020-06-07 12:47:01 UTC
```

I tried:

```
DELETE * FROM my_table
WHERE conversation_id IN (SELECT conversation_id FROM my_table
HAVING count(conversation_id) = 2
GROUP BY 1)
AND min(updated_at)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/45311051/132438:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `deleting.deduplicating_table`
AS
SELECT k.*
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(row ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] k 
  FROM `deleting.deduplicating_table` row
  GROUP BY user_id, conversation_id
)
```