# Big Query | Unnest after Identifying Duplicate Rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to unnest the line_items in my table. However, I have to remove duplicates from our table and it's throwing off what should normally work.

This is the query I use to eliminate duplicates:

```
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS instance
       FROM `shopify.orders` )
      -- identify duplicate rows
   where instance = 1
```

However, when I try to unnest the line_items in this query, it's no longer able to partition by id

```
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS instance
       FROM `shopify.orders`, unnest(line_items) as items )
      -- identify duplicate rows
   where instance = 1
```

Any ideas how I can eliminate duplicates while also unnesting the line_items?

Without removing duplicates, this is what my data looks like:
[image]

When removing duplicates, this is what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, so it is clear what you mean by "duplicate".

Comment: @GordonLinoff you can see the duplicate removal a bit better here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675521/delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-bigquery-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first do dedup and then unnest result - something as in below example

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(instance, line_items) FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS instance
  FROM `shopify.orders` 
), UNNEST(line_items) as item
   -- identify duplicate rows
WHERE instance = 1
```