# How do I restate a partition in C# in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an unpartitionned table in BigQuery called "rawdata".  That table is becoming quite big, and I would like to partition it.  I did not find any way to partition the original table, but according to https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#restating_data_in_a_partition, I can run a command line that will push from unpartitionned "rawdata" into a partitionned table using a query, but only for a specific day/partition.

My instinct was to use the C# API (we already append data through that) to automate the process of doing the bq query --replace restating from the unpartitionned table, but there doesn't seem to be anything that can do that in the C# code.  Do you guys have any recommendation on how to proceed forward?  Should I wrap the bq command line execution instead of using Google API?

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain which portion of the API you are referring to, but it looks like you are referring to the Query API here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query#examples, which won't allow you to pass in a destination table and truncate/append to it.

The Insert API here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert#examples can be used to do what you like by filling in the Configuration.Query part here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query

Specifically, you'd want to specify the **'configuration.query.destinationTable'** field to be the table partition you want to populate, and the **'configuration.query.createDisposition'** and **'configuration.query.writeDisposition'** fields that match your requirements.

This is effectively what the shell client does passing the *'--replace'* and *'--destination_table'* parameters.

Finally, you might want to check this thread for cost considerations when you created a partitioned table from a non-partitioned one: [Migrating from non-partitioned to Partitioned tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993877/migrating-from-non-partitioned-to-partitioned-tables/39001706#39001706)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ahmed's comments I put together some c# code using the c# api client that can restate data for a partition. Our use case was to remove personal information after it's served it's use. The below code will set the second field to a blank value. In the query I noticed you couldn't use the your_table$20180114 syntax in the query that you would use in CLI tool so this is changed to a where clause to retrieve the original data from the corresponding partition.

```
var queryRestateJob = _sut.CreateQueryJob(@"SELECT field1, '' as field2, field3  FROM your_dataset.your_table WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('2018-01-14')",
            new List<BigQueryParameter>(), new QueryOptions
            {
                CreateDisposition = CreateDisposition.CreateIfNeeded,
                WriteDisposition = WriteDisposition.WriteTruncate,
                DestinationTable = new TableReference
                {
                    DatasetId = "your_dataset",
                    ProjectId = "your_project",
                    TableId = "your_table$20180114"
                },
                AllowLargeResults = true,
                FlattenResults = false,
                ProjectId = "your_project"
            })
            .PollUntilCompleted();

            queryRestateJob = queryRestateJob.ThrowOnAnyError();
```