# Is there a way to create custom day partition on BigQuery Tables?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm new to BigQuery and I'm trying to create table with day partition other than the default that google is allowing. Is it possible to back date the DAY partition? Since I'm trying to load historical data I wouldn't be helpful using today for those partition. I'm creating table in BigQuery through Google Storage.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we create dynamic partition in Big Query as in Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546718/can-we-create-dynamic-partition-in-big-query-as-in-hive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use partition decorators to insert data into a specific partition: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#addressing_table_partitions.

bq load 'mydataset.table$20160519' ...