# Partitioning a table

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Bigquery allow partitioning, only by date, at this time.

Lets supose I have a 1billion table rows with `inserted_timestamp` field. Lets supose this field has dates from 1 year ago.

What is the right way to move existing data to a new partitioned table?

**Edited**

I saw there was a elegant solution on Java with version < 2.0 [Sharding BigQuery output tables](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/BigQueryIO) also elaborated at [BigQuery partitioning with Beam streams](https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-partitioning-with-beam-streams-97ec232a1fcc) that is to parametrize table name ( or partition suffix ) windowing data.

But I miss `BigQueryIO.Write` on 2.x beam project also there is no samples about get window time from python serializable function.

I tried to make partitions on pipe but if fails with a large number of partitions ( runs with 100 but fails with 1000 ).

This is my code as far as I could:

```
               (  p
                | 'lectura' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(input_table)
                | 'noheaders' >> beam.Filter(lambda s: s[0].isdigit())
                | 'addtimestamp' >> beam.ParDo(AddTimestampDoFn())
                | 'window' >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(60))
                | 'table2row'  >> beam.Map( to_table_row )  
                | 'write2table' >> beam.io.Write(beam.io.BigQuerySink(
                        output_table,   #<-- unable to parametrize by window
                        dataset=my_dataset, 
                        project=project, 
                        schema='dia:DATE, classe:STRING, cp:STRING, import:FLOAT',
                        create_disposition=CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                        write_disposition=WRITE_TRUNCATE,
                                    )
                                )
                )

p.run()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993877/migrating-from-non-partitioned-to-partitioned-tables should have a couple approaches that are relevant. Also I think you should be able to use JSON or AVRO instead of CSV to avoid working with flat files.

Comment: @NhanNguyen, just edited my question to be more specific. Exists an elegant solution on <2.0 and I miss it on >2.x. Thanks about your link, I followed it and was very related issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the functionality necessary to do this exists in Beam, although it may currently be limited to the Java SDK.

You would use [BigQueryIO](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html). Specifically, you may use [DynamicDestinations](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/DynamicDestinations.html) to determine a destination table for each row.

From the example of DynamicDestinations:

```
events.apply(BigQueryIO.<UserEvent>write()
  .to(new DynamicDestinations<UserEvent, String>() {
        public String getDestination(ValueInSingleWindow<String> element) {
          return element.getValue().getUserId();
        }
        public TableDestination getTable(String user) {
          return new TableDestination(tableForUser(user), 
            "Table for user " + user);
        }
        public TableSchema getSchema(String user) {
          return tableSchemaForUser(user);
        }
      })
  .withFormatFunction(new SerializableFunction<UserEvent, TableRow>() {
     public TableRow apply(UserEvent event) {
       return convertUserEventToTableRow(event);
     }
   }));
```

Comment: Why they are not a python wrapper to do it? I should to afford dataflow projects with Java instead python?  Do you know if Google is foucousing resources on Java?  I mean, if I work in Python I will miss more functionalities than this one? Thanks!

Comment: As this demonstrates, there is differing functionality between the Java and Python SDKs. Addressing these gaps is part of the on-going efforts on Apache Beam. This specific issue is tracked as [BEAM-2801](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2801).