# Big Query specify _PARTITIONTIME when inserting from one table into another

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two Big Query tables, `t1` and `t2`, both of which contain `_PARTITIONTIME` columns.

My goal is to insert rows from `t2` into `t1` in such a way that maintains the `_PARTITIONTIME`

Is there a way of `INSERT`ing the `_PARTITIONTIME` as a selected variable?

Or is there a way of retrospectively defining the `_PARTITIONTIME` column after the rows have been inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can write to partitions using the `partition decorators`

`[TABLE_NAME]$20160501`

however there is a high request feature that is in progress, that will allow you to pick a column and use that as partition day.

In order to write to 20 different partition you need to create at least 20 different queries and writes as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#creating_a_partitioned_table)

```
bq query --allow_large_results --replace --noflatten_results \
--destination_table 'mydataset.temps$20160101' \
'SELECT stn,temp from [bigquery-public-data:noaa_gsod.gsod2016] WHERE mo="01" AND da="01" limit 100'

bq query --allow_large_results --replace --noflatten_results \
--destination_table 'mydataset.temps$20160102' \
'SELECT stn,temp from [bigquery-public-data:noaa_gsod.gsod2016] WHERE mo="01" AND da="02" limit 100'
```

More solutions are addressed here:
[Migrating from non-partitioned to Partitioned tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993877/migrating-from-non-partitioned-to-partitioned-tables/43128826#43128826)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know when this have been implemented, but it works!

> When you use a DML statement to add rows to an ingestion-time
>   partitioned table, you can specify the partition to which the rows
>   should be added. You reference the partition using the _PARTITIONTIME
>   pseudo column.

```
INSERT INTO PROJECT_ID.DATASET.t2 (_PARTITIONTIME, field1, field2) 
SELECT _PARTITIONTIME, field1, field2
FROM PROJECT_ID.DATASET.t1
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/using-dml-with-partitioned-tables#inserting_data_into_ingestion-time_partitioned_tables