# How to create partitioned table from Google Bucket?

Tags: command-line, google-bigquery, gsutil

Every weekend I add a few files to a google `bucket` and then run something from the command line to "update" a table with the new data.

By "update" I mean that I delete the table and then remake it by using all the files in the `bucket`, including the new files.

I do everything by using `python` to execute the following command in the `Windows` command line:

```
bq mk --table --project_id=hippo_fence-5412 mouse_data.partition_test gs://mybucket/mouse_data/* measurement_date:TIMESTAMP,symbol:STRING,height:FLOAT,weight:FLOAT,age:FLOAT,response_time:FLOAT
```

This table is getting massive (>200 GB) and it would be much cheaper for the lab to use partitioned tables.

I've tried a to partition the table in a few ways, including what is recommened by the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables) but I can't make it work.

The most recent command I tried was just inserting `--time_partitioning_type=DAY` like:

```
bq mk --table --project_id=hippo_fence-5412 --time_partitioning_type=DAY mouse_data.partition_test gs://mybucket/mouse_data/* measurement_date:TIMESTAMP,symbol:STRING,height:FLOAT,weight:FLOAT,age:FLOAT,response_time:FLOAT
```

but that didn't work, giving me the error:

```
FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'time_partitioning_type'
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: You sure you can provide the data in the command line? "gs://mybucket/mouse_data/*"? The usage for the command is "bq mk table_name table_schema".

Comment: So the command syntax should be:
bq [--global_flags] <command> [--command_flags] [args]
e.g.:
bq --project_id=... mk --table=... --time_partitioning_type=...

Answer (score 0):

For the old data, a possible solution would be to create an empty partitioned table and then import each bucket file in the desired day partition. Unfortunately it didn’t work with wildcards when I tested it.

**1. Create the partitioned table**

`bq mk --table --time_partitioning_type=DAY [MY_PROJECT]:[MY_DATASET].[PROD_TABLE] measurement_date:TIMESTAMP,symbol:STRING,height:FLOAT,weight:FLOAT,age:FLOAT,response_time:FLOAT`

**2. Import each file in the desired [partition day](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#creating_an_ingestion-time_partitioned_table_when_loading_data).** Here is an example for a file from 22nd February 2018.

`bq load [MY_PROJECT]:[MY_DATASET].[PROD_TABLE]$20180222 gs://MY-BUCKET/my_file.csv`

**3. Process the current uploads normally** and they will be automatically counted in the day of the upload partition.

`bq load [MY_PROJECT]:[MY_DATASET].[PROD_TABLE] gs://MY-BUCKET/files*`

Comment: Check also this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993877/migrating-from-non-partitioned-to-partitioned-tables

Comment: Make sure to have the latest version of Google Cloud SDK by running this command as administrator: `gcloud components update`   link: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes