# BigQuery - Converting from non-partitioned to partitioned table - Legacy SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning

I've looked at previous questions, but the links given to GCP were outdated so I would like to learn what is the best way to do the conversion while inserting the correct partition (meaning not the day i inserted the records, but according to the "date" column.

Could someone point me in the right direction, specifically for Legacy SQL.

Comment: Did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993877/migrating-from-non-partitioned-to-partitioned-tables

Comment: Why legacy? For querying afterwards, or for running the process?

Comment: @GrahamPolley - thank you!, I have - but this method is for Standard SQL, Isn't it?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa - I prefer legacy, I know it's not the common approach but that's what I use currently for my queries. so I assume for your questions - both yes :)

Comment: I strongly recommend you stop using legacySQL unless you're absolutely tied to it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#creating_a_partitioned_table_from_a_query_result): "Currently, legacy SQL is not supported for querying partitioned tables or for writing query results to partitioned tables".

So, in this case, because Legacy can't write to partitioned tables, which seems to be a major blocking with no workarounds, you would have to use Standard SQL or Dataflow, as detailed in the [answers of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993877/migrating-from-non-partitioned-to-partitioned-tables) provided by Graham.