# how to convert an old style partitioned table to a new style partitioned table easily

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a partitioned table with name like `mytable_*` where the suffix denote date.

I would now like to convert this to the new way that tables are to be partitioned in bigquery, ie. with the _partitiondate column, etc.

I was thinking of creating the new table's schema based on the old one, and then to insert data into it, but I am not sure how to put the date value (that is the suffix) of the old table into the `_partitiondate` field.

Comment: I suppose, that this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993877/migrating-from-non-partitioned-to-partitioned-tables is the answer?  I was also thinking that I'll probably have to repopulate with an airflow job, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have previously created date-sharded tables, you can convert the entire set of related tables into a single ingestion-time partitioned table by using the partition command in the bq command-line tool. The date-sharded tables must use the following naming convention: [TABLE]_YYYYMMDD. For example, mytable_20160101, ... , mytable_20160331.

For this you should use `bq partition` command like in example below

```
bq --location=[LOCATION] partition --time_partitioning_type=DAY --time_partitioning_expiration [INTEGER] [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[SOURCE_TABLE]_ [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[DESTINATION_TABLE]
```

You can see more details / options in below articles

[Converting date-sharded tables into ingestion-time partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#converting_date-sharded_tables_into_ingestion-time_partitioned_tables)

and

[bq partition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_partition)

Comment: Is there any way of being able to add clustering during the repartition?