# Can't access BigQuery from AppEngine java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api, google-bigquery

I have an AppEngine account associated with a BigQuery project, but when I try to run a query, I get "Access Denied" in the response. I've setup an AppIdentityCredential like so:

```
 private static AppIdentityCredential getCredential() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    return new AppIdentityCredential(BigqueryScopes.BIGQUERY);
  }

  public static Bigquery createAuthorizedClient() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    return new Bigquery(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredential());
  }
```

I also tried to make my AppEngine account a member of the BigQuery 'team' as directed here:https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization#service-accounts-appengine

However, the teams page on Google's API console says "Invitation sent. Waiting for response" next to my AppEngine Service Account Name.  I didn't receive an invitation (18 hours+) even though I'm the owner and sole team member on both the AppEngine and BigQuery sides.  This leads me to think that BigQuery/AppEngine service integration is just broken, but if anyone sees something I've done wrong I would greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be your team tab in Console project is linked to app engine permissions, that is when it will display pending for mail address that you would like to provide access.

Please try to create new console project with Bigquery API enabled (Optionally GS API). After that add your appengine service account(xxxxxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) with can edit access.

Hope with that you can certainly do what you intend to do.

Also refer post by [Michael Manoochehri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524576/bigquery-and-oauth2) for snippet.

Comment: Thanks. As you suggested, I created a new Console project with BigQuery enabled. However, that automatically creates an associated App Engine project. I disabled the app engine project, but it won't be deleted for 3 days. I then tried to add a different App Engine project via teams with the same result as earlier: Invitation sent. Waiting for response.   Regarding Michael M's post: That example is for OAuth authentication and the snippet requires access to the file system (...   .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("my_file.p12"))", which you cannot do in AppEngine.

Answer (score 0):

I retried a couple times creating new projects and doing the setup in different orders as +Gunasekaran's answer suggested. It worked eventually, but I'm not sure I could do it again let alone explain the correct order of steps.